Flutter Material3 disable appbar color change on scroll (on TabBar)
I just upgraded my flutter version to 3.19. and set userMaterial3 to true. Now, when user scroll, TabBar color change taking primaryColor of the APP (red) with opacity. I wanna know how can I disable that in the App.
Thanks,
I try to avoid this color change when scrolling and I need help to handle this.

Try to set scrolledUnderElevation to 0 in the AppBar.

scrolledUnderElevation: defines The elevation that will be used if
this app bar has something scrolled underneath it.

That's if your TabBar is placed in the bottom of the AppBar. if not then try to provide some code.

Try to put:
shadowColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,

or whatever color you want.
This should disable color change when scrolling
